Bank statement for UK tourist visa
My boyfriend and I want to visit UK for a month. We have already saved a lot of money for this trip but a friend still kindly offered to pay for our flight, our visa and our accommodation during the stay. We still need to prove that we have a monthly income, only our salary is given in cash every month and we pay it into our respective accounts every month. Could this cause a problem? We will still present our pay slip as proof, but will our cash salary pose a problem in terms of the bank statement presented in the visa application?

Cash salary shouldn’t be a problem if you have the supporting paperwork eg salary slip and tax return. I’ve successfully sponsored a UK visitor visa several times for someone paid in cash.

Your friend will need to provide their bank statements and payslips as evidence of their ability to fulfil their commitment to fund your travel costs, and have a good reason for being willing to do so (such as a long-standing friendship that can be proven).

Thank you so much. And how much do we need on our bank statement (for each other) to have more chance being accepted? @Traveller

Unlike Schengen countries, the UK does not specify a minimum cash requirement. They will assess your overall financial situation - see Proportionality in the answer to the duplicate question. If you have a sponsor because you don’t have enough savings to pay for all the trip costs inherently weakens your application - the onus is still on you to meet the rules, see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e

Okay I understand. Is £500 for each one enough for our trip? So we would have £1000 each one on our bank account. We will detail our planning. Is it enough? @Traveller

No-one can answer that question, you’ll find out when you get the decision from UKVI.

Oh okay, thank you so much for your answers. If you have some tips to get visa easier, or to avoid a refusal, please tell me. It is our first application and we do not know everything about it. Thank you so much @Traveller
